# Set Spinner id bt Java Code

Tags: android, android-spinner

I know my question is not that good enough but i am really cant find the answer.My question is how to **set ID of a spinner** by java code (not using xml file)

Comment: Use this: spinner.setId

Comment: its not working.My spinner set id automatically 16908308.I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You can add `id` to your resorces file in values directory.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item
        type="id"
        name="my_id" />
</resources>
```

After that You can set this `id` to Yuor spinner:

```
yourSpinner.setId(R.id.my_id);
```